# The onion link cannot be accessed

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, onion-routing

I can't access onion links that I could access before. I tried using another computer and they still work. When I try to log in I get the error Details: 0xF0 — The requested onion service descriptor can't be found on the hashring and therefore the service is not reachable by the client.
Has anyone had this error before and been able to fix it?
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you're trying the exact same onion address on both computers? You're trying both computers at the same time? And one computer always works and the other doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your other PC with Tor can not bootstrap properly or suffers censorship while working. Attach your logs for more detailed help - but even with the data you've provided - try pre-seeding the faulty computer via another working Internet channel, like mobile 4G: the traffic will not be the issue, wait until it will bootstrap to 100% and try reaching your onion then. If it works - you can swap back your connection and it will use the actual consensus. Also - consider using your working PC as a private bridge for a non-working one, it helps sometimes